Adding an entry to an Entry element duplicates it
I have a site where the database is is some weird state which I would like to fix, but I'm not sure where to start.
I have a channel of entries, and some of these entries (not all of them) suffer from a duplication bug. Not duplicated in general, I only see a single entry elsewhere when listed.
If I have an Entries element elsewhere on the site, where I can select an entry (limited to a single entry), choosing one of these broken entries will list them twice. This also prevents me from saving the entry which has the entries element.
I wonder if anyone has any ideas on where to start looking for erroneous data in the database? This site started out on Craft 3 and has been upgraded to 4, but I don't know when this started.

